How can I disable offline updates in Fedora Workstation 40?
I'm running Fedora Workstation 40 with the Gnome desktop environment.  I'd like to be able to disable the offline updates feature so I don't have to reboot the OS every time updates are installed.  Right now I can work around it by opening a terminal and installing the updates manually, but I'd like to be able to install them from within Gnome Software.

GNOME Software only implements the safer and more reliable reboot-to-install updates. The command line is your only option.
That said, installing updates without rebooting may not actually do what you think. Anything running still using the old versions will still use the old versions. Occasionally, version mismatches between those and newly-launched processes cause crashes (and potentially more insidious invisible failures). So, a reboot is usually advisable anyway.
If the time to install the updates is the main frustration, you might check out Fedora Silverblue or another of our "Atomic Desktop" variants — these still require a reboot, but the update happens instantly (and, as the name says, atomically) so it's much more invisible.

My main problem with reboot-to-install updates is that they are performed on the next boot. There is the option to “install updates and shutdown”, but it actually shuts down and schedules updates on the next boot, so when I turn the computer back on I’m greeted with the Do not touch, updating screen for a few minutes. Is there a way around that other than installing from the command line?

@Ale I'll have to double-check (I'm using Silverblue now), but as I remember, it does apply updates before shutting down. Something strange may be going on.
